# Local type inference and contravariance in generic type variables

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, contravariance, java-10

I came accross the following code:

```
public static <T> Set<T> distinct(
        Collection<? extends T> list,
        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {

    Set<T> set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    set.addAll(list);
    return set;
}
```

This code just uses an intermediate `TreeSet` to remove duplicates, where equality among elements is defined as per the provided comparator.

Let's give local type inference an opportunity, I (naively) thought... So I changed the above code to:

```
public static <T> Set<T> distinct(
        Collection<? extends T> list,
        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {

    var set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    set.addAll(list);
    return set;
}
```

This made sense to me, because the type of `set` can be inferred from the type of `comparator`, or so I thought. However, the modified code doesn't compile and generates the following error:

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.TreeSet<capture#1 of ? super T> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<T>
```

Now, I understand why the error occurs and I admit that the type of the comparator is actually `Comparator<? super T>`, so the type inferred by `var` is `TreeSet<? super T>`.

However, I wonder **why `var` isn't able to infer the generic type of `TreeSet` as just `T` instead of `? super T`**. After all, [according to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)), a `TreeSet<E>` has a constructor that accepts an argument of type `Comparator<? super E>`. So invoking this constructor should create a `TreeSet<E>`, not a `TreeSet<? super E>`. (This is what the first snippet shows). I expected `var` to follow this same logic.

*Note 1:* One way to make the code compile would be to change the return type to `Set<? super T>`. However, that would be a hardly usable set...

*Note 2:* Another way would be to not use contravariance in the comparator, but I don't want this, because I wouldn't be able to use a `Comparator` that compares ancestors of `T`.

*Note 3:* I know that the first snippet works, so it seems obvious that I should stick to not using `var` and declare the set explicitly as `Set<T>`. However, my question is not whether I should discard my second snippet or how to fix it. Instead, I'd like to know why `var` is not inferring `TreeSet<T>` as the type of the `set` local variable in my 2nd snippet.

---

**EDIT 1:** In [this comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41943978#41943978), user @nullpointer correctly points out that I should make the following subtle change to make the 2nd snippet compile:

```
var set = new TreeSet<T>(comparator); // T brings in the magic!
```

Now the generic type parameter `T` is explicit for `TreeSet`, so `var` correctly infers the type of the `set` local variable as `TreeSet<T>`. Still, I'd like to know why I must specify `T` explicitly.

---

**EDIT 2:** In [this other comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41943986#41943986), user @Holger cleverly mentions that the following is *forbidden* in the language:

```
var set = new TreeSet<? super T>(comparator);
```

The code above fails to compile with the following error:

```
java: unexpected type
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found:    ? super T
```

So now the question becomes more evident: if I cannot explicitly specify the bounded generic type `? super T` in the instantiation expression `new TreeSet<? super T>(comparator)`, why is the compiler infering `TreeSet<? super T>` as the type of the `set` local variable?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168213/discussion-on-question-by-federico-peralta-schaffner-local-type-inference-and-co).

Comment: I think it's due to more than two persons involved, so the automatic link doesn't appear and mods have to manually perform the action. If you really want to chat in this scenario, you can refer to this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467

Comment: Well, I guess the comments on the question have been flagged by either moderators or users. You might want to update the question, the links are broken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Brian Goetz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051532/7294647) on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48428434/7294647), he states:

> Local variable type inference says: the types I need are probably already present on the right hand side, why repeat them on the left.

Regarding the code in your question, the only type available to infer (by using the `Comparator` provided) is `TreeSet<? super T>`.  Us humans are smart enough to see that `distinct` returns `set` and expects a `Set<T>`.  However, the compiler either may not be smart enough to resolve it (I'm sure it can), but it's more likely the fact that `var` infers the most specific type using the information provided on the RHS, and the architects didn't want to break that.

Now, as nullpointer stated in their comment, you can explicitly define your `TreeSet` to be of type `T` rather than the inferred capture type `? super T` with the following:

```
var set = new TreeSet<T>(comparator);
```

I'd assume that explicit generic types override inferred types passed to the constructor, which would make sense.

[JLS §14.4.1: Local Variable Declarators and Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/jls10.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A4309%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C350%2Cnull%5D) seems to back up my claim, stating the following:

[image]

**Note**: "upward projection of T", which may just infer to the type (`TreeSet` instead of `Set`), but could possibly include generic type as well.

I believe it's the same reason why `list` in `var list = List.<Number>of(1, 2, 3);` is a `List<Number>` rather than a `List<Integer>`, which works just as well without `var`.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your good answer. Yep, I agree that the types that local type inference needs are on the RHS, and that in my example, the generic type on the RHS is in fact `? super T`. However, I wonder why `var` is mechanically inferring `TreeSet<? super T>`. Who wants a bounded generic type in a local variable? Bounded generic type params are mostly useful when used in method arguments. Can't `var` be intelligent enough as to infer `T`? I guess that this is the heart of my question...

Comment: I'm pretty sure type inference won't search for hints beyond the current statement.  If the statement is a `return`, it may consult the current method's signature, and if the statement contains method invocations, it may probe the signatures of the invoked methods.  It will not, however, look ahead at future uses of the assignment target.  It won't inspect the return value because the return statement occurs after the current statement.  Thus, the type of `var set` will be inferred _without_ consulting the signature of the declaring method.

Comment: I believe it *can* be intelligent enough, but, as Mike just stated above, there's no reason it should look ahead, since it only uses the information on the RHS of the same line to infer the type.  If that were to be a future modification, I would definitely welcome it!

Comment: @MikeStrobel yes, I understand that type inference doesn't look ahead, and I'm not claiming that it should do that in this case. I understand that `var` is designed to look for the type at the RHS only, and that's OK. I wonder why the type for `set` is inferred as `TreeSet<? super T>` instead of `TreeSet<T>`. My point is: couldn't type inference be improved in this case? I see no point in having a local variable with a bounded generic type, especially if the generic type is represented by a type variable and not by an actual type.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner every time we, devs, find such a case, tend to think why not here too? I've heard this many times already as an argument, I guess this could have been done, but its either not that simple as it looks, or will bring more sophisticated code along, for a not that often case. I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Using the local variable in your second snippet requires you to explicitly specify the bound of the `TreeSet` as in :

```
public static <T> Set<T> distinct(Collection<? extends T> list, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    var set = new TreeSet<T>(comparator);
    set.addAll(list);
    return set;
}
```

the reason being that the inferred var otherwise makes use of the most obvious bound used with the comparator and gets inferred as `TreeSet<? super T>` and fails with the stated compilation error due to the incompatibility of conversion.

> why I must specify T explicitly

<strike>Thinking the other way round as pointed by Jacob as well and formulating the code as</strike>

```
  private static Set<Integer> distincts(Collection<? extends Integer> list, Comparator<Number> comparator) {
        var set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        // if you don't specify the bound, you get a compiler error on the return statement 
        // since the inferred type would be `Number`
        set.addAll(list);
        return set;
    }
```

To simply question back, what type would you want to be inferred here by default for `TreeSet`? `Integer`, `Byte` which one from the list of subclasses of `Number` and how(based on the return type which might just be inferred far later)?

***Edit***:- I do second the thought that given the constructor **[`TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator))** constructs a `TreeSet<E>`, hence invocation of such constructor should be inferred as `TreeSet<E>` instead of `TreeSet<? super E>`. Also, as [Brian commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616434/local-type-inference-and-contravariance-in-generic-type-variables#comment86247263_496164340), not everything could be inferred and for any such specific types, one could ask for it(assuming on the [jdk mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jdk-dev)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's not so obvious that the bound used by the comparator is the one to be machanically inferred by `var`, that's the point of my question. Regarding your example next to the end of your answer, I think it's a different situation than my question's. You should receive a `Comparator<? super Integer>` to make it anaogous, then you could invoke the method with some `Comparator<Number>` or `Comparator<Integer>`. Now you'll get an incompatible types compilation error that mimics mine's, though with the specific type `Integer` instead of with just `T`.