# How do "var" and raw types come together?

Tags: java, generics, var, local-variables, java-10

I came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51705645/1531124) that suggests to use

```
var list = new ArrayList();
```

I was surprised to find a raw type here, and I am simply wondering: does `var` use the `<>` "automatically?

( in the meantime, the answer was changed to use `<String>`, but I am still curious about but "principles" here )

I saw other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428434/java-10-will-java-7s-diamond-inference-work-with-local-type-inference), but they all use the diamond operator:

```
var list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I am simply wondering: does `var` change how we should (not) be using raw types? Or is that suggestion to leave out `<>` simply bad practice?

Comment: FYI, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705558/java-interface-as-reference-type/51705645#51705645) you've linked in your first sentence was edited by the author to add `<String>`.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Same question to you: where in that question is *any* discussion regarding the usage of raw types in conjunction with var?

Comment: Nice question. I guess [this article by Brian](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/jep-286/lvti-faq.html) and [another one by Stuart](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) could be good reads to get to know better about the styles and risks. Holger was [pointing to the raw types as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428434/java-10-will-java-7s-diamond-inference-work-with-local-type-inference#comment83914648_48429067), I would guess, he saw such a question coming somewhere down the line.

Comment: It's pretty simple.  For a `var`-declared local, we compute the type of the RHS as a standalone expression (and then perform a procedure called _upward projection_ to project away capture variables.)  If the RHS is raw, then the inferred type is a raw type.  No magic.

Comment: @SudhirOjha I don’t think this is a duplicate of my question, as mine doesn’t really refer to raw types at all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I came across an answer that suggests to use...

<s>I would ignore that answer</s>, because as you point out, it uses raw types **and** it types `list` as specifically `ArrayList`. *(Update: The answerer edited [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705558/java-interface-as-reference-type/51705645#51705645) to add an element type.)* Instead:

```
List<AppropriateElementType> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

According to the [second answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429050/157247), `var` *will* cause the compiler to infer an element type from the right-hand side if you include the `<>`, picking the most specific type it can. In `var list = new ArrayList<>();` that would be `ArrayList<Object>`, though, because it doesn't have anything more specific it can choose.

**But**, this:

```
var list = new ArrayList();
```

...without the `<>`, is using a raw type (`ArrayList`), not a parameterized type with `Object` as the parameter (`ArrayList<Object>`), which is different.

---

If the use of `list` is sufficiently contained (a few lines in a method), having it typed `ArrayList<X>` rather than `List<X>` may be acceptable (depends on your coding style), in which case:

```
var list = new ArrayList<AppropriateElementType>();
```

But generally I prefer to code to the interface rather than the concrete class, even with locals. That said, with locals, it *is* less important than with instance members, and `var` is convenient.

Comment: Being the answerer in the original question I just want to note that this was an off-hand reference to how a `var` expression would look in the context of the original answer and I forgot to move the type information from the left side (which was replaced by var) to the right side.  Before I noticed this was commented upon and had a chance to fix it, this question was asked.

Answer (score 10):

It is legal to use both `var` and `diamond`, but the inferred type will change:

```
var list = new ArrayList<>(); // DANGEROUS: infers as ArrayList<Object>
```

For its inference,  `diamond`  can use the target type (typically,  the left-hand side of a declaration) or the types of constructor arguments. If neither is present, it falls back to the broadest applicable type, which is often `Object`<sup>1</sup>.

With both `diamond` and generic methods, additional type information can be provided by actual args to the constructor or method, allowing the intended type to be inferred<sup>1</sup>:

```
var list = List.of(BigInteger.ZERO); // OK: infers as List<BigInteger>
var list = new ArrayList<String>( ); // OK: infers as ArrayList<String>
```

In view of the above, I don't recommend to do the following (because you will get the raw `ArrayList` type):

```
var list = new ArrayList(); // DANGEROUS: infers as ArrayList
```

### Conclusion:

1. Don't use raw types irrespective of the presence or absence of `var`.
2. Ensure that method or constructor arguments provide enough type information so that the inferred type matches your intent. Otherwise, avoid using both `var` with `diamond`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - [**Style Guidelines**](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) for Local Variable Type Inference: G6. Take care when using var with diamond or generic methods.</sup>